# $H \leq K \leq G \implies |G: K| \leq |G:H|$

Tags: group-theory

Let $H \leq K \leq G$ be subgroups of each other.

Is the following inequality always true?

$$|G:K | \leq |G:H|$$

Intuitively, it should be.

I tried to define $$\psi: G/K \to G/H: gK \mapsto gH$$

Problem is that this does not seem well-defined!

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the opposite, define $\varphi: G/H\to G/K$ by $gH\to gK$. This one is well defined, because if $g_1H=g_2H$ then $g_1^{-1}g_2\in H\leq K$, and hence $g_1K=g_2K$. $\varphi$ is also onto, because $gK=\varphi(gH)$ for all $g\in G$. Hence $|G/K|\leq |G/H|$.

Comment: I just figured this out haha. Thanks.