# Prove that $[G:K]=[G:H][H:K] $where $K\le H \le G$

Tags: group-theory

I am basically not able to understand how to start.  Can someone help me to see the picture (probably draw diagrams of cosets) instead of giving some formal proof.I want to see as to why this is happening

Comment: Each coset of $H$ in $G$ can be partitioned into $[H:K]$ different cosets of $K$.  Does that help?

Comment: Also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3502244/h-leq-k-leq-g-implies-g-k-leq-gh). All I did was search for the tag `[group-theory]` and `K\leq H\leq G`. It should have been easy to find lots of duplicates of this.

Comment: Sometimes it would be necessary to say  "please search before posting", especially for very popular questions in an area.

Comment: Yeah I did search but most of the time it was formal proof and I couldn't get the geometry behind it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just like slicing a cake (the whole group $G$) into $[G:H]$ equal slices, and these latter in turn into $[H:K]$ equal smaller slices each. In how many small slices would be $G$ finally sliced into? This number is precisely $[G:K]$.